# Error in SQlite syntax i dont know whats wrong

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I wonder what's wrong with my sql syntax.Its working on mysql but for sqlite gives me error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `points` (
                                     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                                     `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
                                     `longitude` double NOT NULL, 
                                     `latitude` double NOT NULL, 
                                     `radius` double NOT NULL, 
                                     `image` blob NOT NULL, 
                                     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                                    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

INSERT INTO `points` (`id`, `name`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `radius`, `image`) 
VALUES      (1, 'Isfahan, Iran', 51.678314, 32.65036, 0.064486, 
             0xffd8ffe000104a46494600010001009600960000fffe001f4c45414420546563686e6f6c6f6769657320496e632e2056312e303100ffdb008400100b0c0e0c0a100e0d0e1211101318281a181616183123251d283b343e3d3a34393841495d4f414558463839516f52586063696a693f4e737b72667a5d676964011112121815182f1a1a2f644339436464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464ffc4003000000203010000000000000000000000000001020304050101010101010100000000000000000000000102030405ffc20011
```

Comment: I think **AUTOINCREMENT** is one word - http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Actually looks like there's a bunch of things in that statement that are mySql specific..

Comment: Yeah, `ENGINE=MyISAM` for example.

Comment: Thank you,so how can I check my syntax without installing a SQlite database?I mean Is there any tool for example?

Comment: @user1492637 try sqlfiddle.com where you can test any database, not just SQLite

Comment: @nawfal Ahhh yess thank you I've searched a lot but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It should be `AUTOINCREMENT` as one word.
2. You dont require this statement: `ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4;` which is MySQL specific. Further more, if you are setting the autoincrement value to start from 5, then you shouldn't be inserting an id of value equal to 1.
3. You do not seem to have a closing bracket after the insert statement.

You should instead try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `points` (
                                     `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                                     `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, 
                                     `longitude` double NOT NULL, 
                                     `latitude` double NOT NULL, 
                                     `radius` double NOT NULL, 
                                     `image` blob NOT NULL
                                    );

INSERT INTO `points` (`id`, `name`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `radius`, `image`) 
VALUES      (1, 'Isfahan, Iran', 51.678314, 32.65036, 0.064486, 
             0xffd8ffe000104a46494600010001009600960000fffe001f4c45414420546563686e6f6c6f6769657320496e632e2056312e303100ffdb008400100b0c0e0c0a100e0d0e1211101318281a181616183123251d283b343e3d3a34393841495d4f414558463839516f52586063696a693f4e737b72667a5d676964011112121815182f1a1a2f644339436464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464646464ffc4003000000203010000000000000000000000000001020304050101010101010100000000000000000000000102030405ffc20011);
```

There could be more fixes required as well. Back tick though recognized by SQLite, is a MySQL specific quoting.